# Breeze registerEntityTypeCtor not working

Tags: breeze, hottowel

I am working on a Hottowel project and I want to format some data passed on from database to Breeze, but it looks like the ctor is not getting registered.

What am I doing wrong?

In `datacontext.js`:

```
    var manager = configureManager();

    function configureManager() {
        var mng = new breeze.EntityManager('breeze/data');
        breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
        model.configureMetadataStore(mng.metadataStore);

        return mng;
    }
```

In `model.js`:

```
    function configureMetadataStore(metadataStore) {
        metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor
            ('UserInfo', null, userInfoInitializer);
    }

    function userInfoInitializer() {
        if (this.Email == "")
            this.Email = '---';

        this.CreateDate = formatDateTime(this.CreateDate);
    }

    function formatDateTime(DateTime) {
        return moment.utc(DateTime).format('DD. MM. YYYY. [у] hh:mm');
    }
```

Datacontext has a reference to model, the data is transferred from database and appears on the screen, but is not formatted. `console.log()` calls from `userInfoInitializer()` are not appearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I am constructing an entity, my constructor needs to have an entity to construct.  I have not tried your above code but I believe that Breeze passes an entity in and you need to give that entity properties.  Using this. MAY work but it is the first thing that stands out to me.

```
function userInfoInitializer(user) {
    if (user.Email == "")
        user.Email = "---";
```

2nd - What is your entity named in your model?  Is it UserInfo or just User?  You probably already know this but you need to make sure when you are adding a constructor you use the properly named Entity.

3rd - If you are using camelCase then you need to leave the first letter of the property lowercase.  Ex . user.email and user.createDate.

Last, I can't tell if you are creating a 'createDate' in the constructor or that is being passed from your model.  If it is indeed a property you are creating I would recommend making it an knockout observable or computed property.  If it is coming from the database then you need to do something like

```
if (!user.createDate) { } //set it
```

Remember that all of the entities being returned from the database will be given that property, so if you have entities that already have a createDate in your example you are overriding that date.  If you want to set createDate to now then I would move that into your method where you are creating the object.

Comment: Not using `this` anymore, it still doesn't work. I forgot to mention, `UserInfo` isn't a table in the database, but there is a class UserInfo in the models. I use it for displaying user information on his personal profile page, but I can't load everything (like password) for obvious reasons. It seems like the initializer is not getting registered.

Comment: Are you mapping partials back to the parent object properly? If not your initializer won't realize that UserInfo is a User. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091496/using-partials-and-projections-of-entities-in-web-api

Comment: Thanks, this post helped me very much. I ended up using `[JsonIgnore]`, since password should never go over the net.